# Run button click functionality from command prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd, buttonclick

I have a wpf application,Now I want to run the button_click functionality from the Command prompt.

**EDIT:**
The button click collect the list of drivers and show it. Now I want to call this method from command prompt.

Comment: Why you just want to run this method??
I guess for testing the functionallity? If yes, why not creating a testcase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() to retrieve the parameters passed from the command line at any point.

```
if( Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Any( cmd => cmd == "--click-button" ) )
{
    do_button_click_method();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

import DLL

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern System.IntPtr GetCommandLine();
```

in your Form_OnLoad

```
IntPtr ptr = GetCommandLine();

var commandline = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandline) && commandline == "yourCommand")
{
    button_click(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Now, you can run button_click function from commandline